# How to auto copy the number from textbox to another textbox when entering the number

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

I have a EditorFor as below:

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Price, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", id = "txtprice" } })
```

and a label or input as below:

```
<input id="priceNumber" name="priceNuber" /> USD
```

when entering the price number into text of EditorFor then will auto paste the price number to priceNumber.

Answer (score 0):

Try this jquery

```
$("#txtprice").keyup(function() {
     $("#priceNumber").val($("#txtprice").val());
}
```